# Newtonsoft Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: c#, json.net

I got a json with some nested object, for example:

```
{
  "OrganizationData": {
    "Org1": {
      "Name": "Rega And Dodli",
      "EmployessNum": "100000000"
    },
    "Org2": {
      "Name": "Sami And Soso",
      "EmployessNum": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to remove "Org1" using the `SelectToken` method.

What I tried to do is:

```
json.SelectToken("OrganizationData.Org1").Parent.Remove();
```

but then I get the error

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

but if I try to remove the name and not the entire org, it does work when doing it like this: `json.SelectToken("OrganizationData.Org1.Name").Parent.Remove();`

How can I fix it?

The entire code:

```
dynamic json = new JObject();
        json.OrganizationData = new JObject();
        json.OrganizationData.Org1 = new JObject();
        json.OrganizationData.Org1.Name = "Rega And Dodli";
        json.OrganizationData.Org1.EmployessNum = "100000000";
        json.OrganizationData.Org2 = new JObject();
        json.OrganizationData.Org2.Name = "Sami And Soso";
        json.OrganizationData.Org2.EmployessNum = "2";
        json.SelectToken("OrganizationData.Org1").Remove();
```

Comment: Remove `Parent`, your trying to remove the Parent of Org1. Parent works with `Org1.Name` cause `Org1` is Name's parent.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code used please.

Comment: @mxmissile if I remove the parent, I get another exception: "'Cannot add or remove items from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.'" but then I also get it when trying to remove the name. I don't think you can remove it

Comment: @NolanBradshaw I have added the entire code. It's only a testing program so it's literally all the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following to get Org1 removed.

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(@"{
'OrganizationData': {
'Org1': {
    'Name': 'Rega And Dodli'
},
'Org2': {
    'Name': 'Sami And Soso'
}}}");

json.SelectToken("OrganizationData.Org1").Parent.Remove();
```

If you want to use 'dynamic', you need to convert it to JObject first, otherwise you will get 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference'.

```
dynamic x = new JObject();
x.OrganizationData = new JObject();
x.OrganizationData.Org1 = new JObject();
x.OrganizationData.Org1.Name = "Tarzan and Jane";
x.OrganizationData.Org2 = new JObject();
x.OrganizationData.Org2.Name = "Sami And Soso";
JObject json = JObject.FromObject(x); //This is the trick
json.SelectToken("OrganizationData.Org1").Parent.Remove();
```

Comment: Your code works but I don't understand why mine doesn't.. the difference between our code is that you use JObject.Parse while I used a dynamic var to build the json.. Is it wrong to do it like that?

Comment: Your code dynamic json = new JObject(); and so on produces a different json.

Comment: Yes. Why does it matter? It's one of the ways from the Newtonsoft documentation

Comment: See my edited answer, you need to convert the 'dynamic' to JObject.

Answer (score 0):

```
json.SelectToken("OrganizationData").Property("Org1").Remove();
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: The problem is that the "OrganizationData.Org1" is an unknown input. Org1 is just what I've tried for the sake of the example

Comment: Can you try this? json.SelectToken("OrganizationData").Property("Org1").Remove(); I have updated my answer, if it works can you Mark :)

Comment: but like I said, the input is "OrganizationData.Org1". I'm talking about a situation where I have no knowledge of the json in advanced at all

Comment: So i am confused, so you dont know the name of Org1? If that is the case and you know the position you could delete the child by position?

Comment: I don't even know that there is something called "Org1". This json was just an example to show what I want to do. I need to get a key from the user and simply remove it from the json, but the key string is of the format of "primeKey.SubKey1.SubKey2" and so forth

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for using `dynamic` here?
Try to do in this way:

```
var json = new JObject();
        json["OrganizationData"] = new JObject();
        json["OrganizationData"]["Org1"] = new JObject();
        json["OrganizationData"]["Org1"]["Name"]= "Rega And Dodli";
        json["OrganizationData"]["Org1"]["EmployessNum"] = "100000000";
        json["OrganizationData"]["Org2"] = new JObject();
        json["OrganizationData"]["Org2"]["Name"] = "Sami And Soso";
        json["OrganizationData"]["Org2"]["EmployessNum"] = "2";
        json.SelectToken("OrganizationData.Org1").Parent.Remove();
```